# How to show time which is less than a day?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar

This code will return number of days between two days.

How to determine when time will pass and day become hours like (20 hours) or (40 minutes), then how do I check that it's a day or less than a day.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfDaysUntilDay:(NSDate *)aDate
{

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                fromDate:self
                                                  toDate:aDate options:kNilOptions];

    return [components day];    
}
```

Comment: [NSDateComponentsFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDateComponentsFormatter_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015130)

Comment: You used NSCalendarUnitDay, just try unitHour or UnitMinute?

Comment: Use `timeIntervalSinceDate:` to get the time remaining is seconds ,result / 3600 for hours remaining, (result % 3600) / 60 for minutes remaining and (result %3600) % 60 for seconds remaining.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSCalendarUnitSecond` instead.

```
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitSecond
                                               fromDate:date
                                                 toDate:aDate options:kNilOptions];
```

Later you can convert seconds to any unit (hour, day, year).

Comment: but how to determine when time will pass and day become hours like (20 hours), then how do I check that its a day or less then a day.